# Looking for an A4-wide cabled portable thermal direct printer, can be old

Tags: printer, portable

I am looking for a thermo printer that can print on A4-wide thermo paper (rolls, like FAX-rolls) and otherwise is quite small.

I do not need an inbuild battery or such, I do not need any wireless data transfer (and I in fact do need some kind of wired data transfer).

Very small ones I only find Brother [PJ-622](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/brother-pocketjet-pj-622-pj622z1-a633851.html?plz=&t=v&va=b&vl=de&hloc=at&hloc=de&hloc=pl&hloc=uk&hloc=eu&v=e#filterform%20Brother%20PJ-622) and PJ-623 for under 200 EUR. Aren't there more? Maybe (very) old models? In fact, it's just a telefax without all the telephony stuff ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the Pentax PocketJet/ Pentax PocketJet 200/ Pentax PocketJet II/ Pentax PocketJet 3, the 200 (200 dpi) or II (300 dpi) at eBay for prices ranging 60 USD and up and they come with an interface that both accepts parrallel ("LPT") and serial ("COM") connection, having the corresponding adapter cable.

Pentax [PocketJet 200](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Pentax/Pentax-PocketJet_200) and [II](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Pentax/Pentax-PocketJet_II) have [CUPS support](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/pentaxpj/).